# Add key and value to an existing Object in Angular Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add a value to an existing Object in Angular , I am getting the object from a service call and before saving it to local storage i want to save the time stamp .

I am using `Object.assign` for the same

The problem is that user is a typed with an Interface and if i add any property to it says that the property is not defined in interface and the interface class is not written by me its by Firebase User info . i donot want to edit that interface or add to it . I want to create a new one property dynamically.

**Like Reflection in Java and also adding dynamic Value to object in Javascript.**

This is what i have tried

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("Here");
  if (data) {
    const value = Object.assign(data,{TimeStamp : new Date().getTime()}); // this assign is not working even having obj in variable dosent help  
    console.log("Value"+JSON.stringify(value));
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(value));
    this.user = data;
    this.service.fetchData(this.user.uid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.comments = res;
    });
  } else {
    this.comments = null;
  }
});
```

Any Help Thanks in Advance

Comment: ... no need to use object assign if the object exists, just add it on the fly `data.newProperty = someValue`

Comment: instead of `console.log("Here");` please try `console.log(data);` and paste the output in ques

Comment: You haven't identified a specific problem ... or asked a question here

Comment: @AJT_82 the problem is that user is a typed with an Interface and if i add any property to it says that the property is not defined in interface and the interface class is not written by me its by Firebase User info . i donot want to edit that interface or add create a new one i want to add this property dynamically

Comment: Ah the downside of static OOP interfaces rears its ugly head.

Comment: @Dhyey the data is comming from firebase and contains user info so i cannot paste it here

Comment: @TimConsolazio ya any help on this tim will update the question accordindly

Comment: @RahulSingh, if you are only using javascript, you can use angular.extend({}, object1, object2). Object.assign is available only on ES6.

Comment: i am using angular 4 actually

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes angular 4 using ts

Comment: @AJT_82 ny suggestions

Comment: Please comment for downvoting

Comment: Its a shame there is no reason for a downvote ?

Comment: And usually you won't get a reason for this, but you're not new here and so should already know this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i know that but at least a reason helps me improve the question . as the answers aren't working out.

Comment: I can't help since I do not code with either tool, but if you need a better answer, why not strive to improve it in any way that you can and add a bounty to your question?

Comment: I am working on it if i dnt work it out today will surely open a bounty thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use the assignment as Mentioned below** `data.TimeStamp = new Date().getTime()` is the right way.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("Here");
  if (data) {
   data.TimeStamp = new Date().getTime() // this assign is not working even having obj in variable dosent help  
    console.log("Value"+JSON.stringify(data));
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
    this.user = data;
    this.service.fetchData(this.user.uid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.comments = res;
    });
  } else {
    this.comments = null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Firebase User interface and add the Timestamp, then use your extended interface in place of the default one.

```
interface MyUser extends User {
    timeStamp: any;
}
```

Then you can add the timeStamp to the data object like this:

```
 data.timestamp = {TimeStamp : new Date().getTime()}
 console.log("data",data);
```

You don't need to use Object.assign, you can just add a value for a key directly on the object.

You'll want to specify the correct type for the timeStamp in your interface, if you're carrying the value as a string, make that a string, but any is a safe place to start.

Make sure to make your local user variable is typed to your extended interface.

```
public user: MyUser;

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("Here");
  if (data) {
    data.timestamp = {TimeStamp : new Date().getTime()}
    console.log("data: "+JSON.stringify(data));
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
    this.user = data;
    this.service.fetchData(this.user.uid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.comments = res;
    });
  } else {
    this.comments = null;
  }
});
```

Comment: when i do this i get another error in compilation 
Saying ERROR in 
C:/Users/c1xadmin/WebstormProjects/AngularConcepts/src/app/comment/comment.component.ts (80,16): Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'User'.

I think the type of data is type user from firebase and some how typescript is able to infer not sure any suggestions

Comment: You have to cast the data time to MyUser - it's a more broadly scoped instance of User, so it should work. I would also suggest making your additions to the returned data after assigning it to the local this.user. See my edits above.

Comment: still the same error ERROR what can be the possible reason

C:/Users/c1xadmin/WebstormProjects/AngularConcepts/src/app/comment/comment.component.ts (85,16): Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'User'.

ERROR in C:/Users/c1xadmin/WebstormProjects/AngularConcepts/src/app/comment/comment.component.ts (89,11): Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'MyUser'.